# NSInputStream - appending data without using NSMutable data appending

Tags: ios, inputstream, nsinputstream

I want to appending the data in NSInputStream without using NSMutable data append.

Is it possible to do it?

Please guide me

Comment: if you dont use mutableData, you can create a new instance everytime and keep on appending. But not the best way.

Comment: Hi Thanks Anoop. Please make me clear. create new instance means?

Comment: just like `NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",oldString];` inssstead of this you can use mutablestring and keep on appeding.

Comment: Girija, Please say in more detail what you are trying to do. If you are appending to the data, are you sure you want to use NSInputStream? It sounds to me like you want to be using NSOutputStream.